# How to save custom type array using FileManager?

Tags: swift

I have this custom type FileManager

```
class Article: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    static func == (lhs: Article, rhs: Article) -> Bool {
        lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
    var hashValue: Int {
          return self.id.hashValue
        }
    
    var id: UUID
    var title: String
    var text: String
     
    init(id: UUID, title: String, text: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

And have this custom type array:

```
@State var articles = [Article]()
```

I tried to save and loading it back using following method, but it doesn't work.
Here's what I have tried:

saving:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
                        
let arrayURL = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent("articles")

let arrayData = NSArray(array: articles).data(from: 0, to: articles.count)
let success = arrayData.write(to: arrayURL, atomically: true)
```

loading it back:

```
let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
let arrayURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("articles")
let arrayData = fileManager.data(contentsOf: arrayURL)
let myArray = NSArray.array(from: arrayData, of: [Article].self)
```

But both of them doesn't work, can anyone help me with this?

EDIT:
I tried this solution but it didn't work: [Whats the best practice to save and load array of struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475342/whats-the-best-practice-to-save-and-load-array-of-struct)

Size of array is big. so using UserDefaults seems not a good option.
Experienced data loss and takes too long time saving it.(I'm trying ti save data moment before if app gonna crash.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Whats the best practice to save and load array of struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56475342/whats-the-best-practice-to-save-and-load-array-of-struct)

Comment: No, I tried that before, but using UserDefaults does not suit for me because the size of array is too big. Experienced data loss.

Comment: You don't need to save the data to user defaults. Use the answer in that link to properly convert your array into data. Then write the data to a file instead of user defaults.

Comment: Perhaps this is a better one: [Save object to json files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50461984/save-object-to-json-files). Or [Storing an array of an array of a custom class - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828405/storing-an-array-of-an-array-of-a-custom-class-swift)

Comment: @HangarRash Thanks, solution in the second link worked for me